# tar: How to recover from Unexpected EOF in file

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, ram, tar, split

### Background

I made a tar archive.

I made it on a ram disk with a limit of 4096M for the sake of the argument lets say the directory that I was archiving was 5000M. (It doesn't matter how big the directory is, just that it requires more space then I'm giving it.)

As expected at some point the disk fills up and the last entry fails. Something along the lines of 4096 bites out of 10something bytes written; Errors and failures Exiting. (I lost the message I'll reproduce it if it's needed).

There is an unexpected EOF at the end of the tar archive and I cannot update once it's in a larger (and slower) directory due to this EOF thing.

---

## Question

Is there a way I can repair the .tar archive from an EOF cutoff mid stream?

As I would like to continue to expand/update this archive in the larger (and slower) drive

Is this impossible and I am just going to have to suffer and write from the beginning to the larger (and MUCH SLOWER) drive?

I'm going to end up doing this multiple times so speed is a factor.

Comment: Can it be done, I bet it can from my reading of (http://gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) "Physically, an archive consists of a series of file entries terminated by an end-of-archive entry, which consists of two 512 blocks of zero bytes. A file entry usually describes one of the files in the archive (an archive member), and consists of a file header and the contents of the file. File headers contain file names and statistics, checksum information which tar uses to detect file corruption, and information about file types." ...

Comment: ...  Read from eof() & continue back until you get a bad checksum then continue from that spot.  If that has already been done, I don't know sorry.

Comment: Maybe you could look back to `tar`'s origins (as a **t**ape **ar**chiver) by splitting your ram disk into two volumes and then following something like the procedure described here: [Using Multiple Tapes](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/tar/html_node/tar_136.html#SEC131)

Comment: For myself if I try to put something too big onto something too small, I make that which is too small bigger. I have 8 GB of RAM but many terabytes of storage so I would never use RAM as a pseudo-storage device. The exception is for Intel Fake RAID (RST) or Optane as it's now called. However in that case it's a block device and not a real storage device.

Comment: @steeldriver your comment was the crucial piece to solving my problem.
Thank you! I don't know if you wanted to write an answer but I was able to use the -L 4096M option which worked like a charm!
I'll append the second archive when it's finished.

Comment: @haelmic I was really only speculating - if you've managed to make something work, then please write your own answer. I look forward to learning!

Comment: Your basic problems seems to be slow copy to your hdd.  tar has a blocking switch, -b, which allows you to specify a blocking factor n, of 512 byte blocks.  Consider giving it something big, so your block is at least 2meg in size.  Helps minimize the system buffers fragging(?) and grinding things to a crawl.

Comment: The archive I've been using for testing has more errors then I realized. I will move on to another archive for future testing.  It could be the case that I had odd blocks that were corrupting things in different ways. I only suspect that might be the case as, I can't remember which part worked before and which part after changing the block size from 512bytes to 4096bytes thank you @ubfan for the suggestion . I don't know if changing the block size correctly will solve it but, I will continue testing to see if it was just the archive or something else.